# Facebook api not passing user info to integrated site, if user already logged into facebook directly and try to login from integrated site

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I am working on login with facebook into our site. I am using facebook js sdk for this. Now, if I clicked on fb login button (which is placed in our site), it opens a popup window asking for user name and password. If I login here by entering correct username and password, its logging in, after that, it gives the required info to me. so, I am passing that info into our site and logging the user. No issue in this flow. But, if user already logged into facebook directly by opening facebook.com from browser and opened our site in separate tab . Our site will also contains "login with facebook" button. So, when user clicks on this button, it opens a login window and closes immediately without giving any user info. I guess it is because, user already logged into facebook. But here also I need the logged in user info. How do I achieve this?

Please help me out.
Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: `FB.login` returns the same info, regardless of whether the user was logged in to Facebook and your app already or not.

Comment: here check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/

Comment: @CBore, Thanks for your reply. If I use FB.login, it directly  gives info, without clicking on login button, if user has already logged in. But my requirement is when I clicked on "fb-login" button, then only it has to get user info so that I can get the info and pass it into my application. Any suggestion would be appreciable.